# Best way to squash migrations django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-migrations

I had 10 migrations and I wanted to keep them in one file . So I squash them using  `./manage.py squashmigrations  accounts`  . Now I had  11  files including  init and squash file. so I deleted 9 other files and kept  init and squash and run `migration` and `migrate` .

Now want to ask Is this proper way  ? and I have another app with same scenario should I do same to that ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes that's basically the way to do it :)
Django has a great documentation about how to squash migrations and the appropriate workflow. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#migration-squashing

In short,

1. Create a squash migration and add it to your other migrations
2. Once you applied all current migrations to your environment(s), you can delete the old files as you did.

But additionally, you should

3. make sure other apps that referenced a deleted migration are updated to link to your new squash migration file
4. delete the `replaces` attribute inside of the squash migration, so that it is considered as a plain migration (and not a squash migration anymore)

Then you're done and you can repeat the process for other apps, the same one again once more migrations accumulated again.